# Can't call a method inside a setter? (Operator)

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I would like to understand what is happening here.

I'm simply trying to call a method inside the setter of a property in an Operator (in order to not repeat code). But I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'OBJECT_OT_simple_operator' object has no attribute 'hi'
```

Sample/template script:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import IntProperty

def main(context):
    for ob in context.scene.objects:
        print(ob)


class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}

    def hi(self):
        print("Hello") 

    def get_var(self):
        return self.get("a_var", 1)
    
    def set_var(self, value):
        self["a_var"] = value

        self.hi()
        

    
    a_var: IntProperty(
        name="a_var",
        default=1,
        set=set_var,
        get=get_var
    )
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        frames_row = layout.row()
        layout.use_property_split = True
        frames_row.prop(self, "a_var", text="a_var")


    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text=SimpleOperator.bl_label)


# Register and add to the "object" menu (required to also use F3 search "Simple Object Operator" for quick access).
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.simple_operator()
```

I'm still learning to develop addons in Blender, but I remember calling (without problems) methods inside setters in other class (even though, those classes inherited from `PropertyGroup`, not `Operator`).

What is happening here?

Thank you so much for the help.